# azure mobile services error cannot find module 'azure-storage'

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-table-storage

I have been using [Azure-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-storage)  npm module in my AzureMobileService custom API for past couple of months and all has been working fine, till couple of days back it started giving me this error - cannot find module 'azure-storage'. Its strange because I haven't changed my code a bit, actually the day it start giving me this error, I had checked my app(HTML/JS app) in the morning, it was all working good. But when I came back from work and ran the app, I got this error. below is the code in my custom api where I get this error

```
var azure = require('azure-storage');
var retryOperationFilter = new azure.ExponentialRetryPolicyFilter();
var tableService= azure.createTableService().withFilter(retryOperationFilter);
```

and I do have azure-storage included in my package.json -

```
"dependencies": {"tracer": "0.7.3", "colors" : "1.0.3", "lodash" :"2.4.1", "azure-storage": "0.4.1"},
```

I asked this [question](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/issues/39) at 'Azure-storage' npm page, but didn't get much help, so now trying here; its been two days now and I haven't got it resolved, its very annoying and I am at my wits end.
anyone out there has experienced same or may have any idea, will much appreciate if you can kindly share anything you may have got on this.

Comment: It looks like 0.4.2 was published ~ 10 days ago by the Azure team. Perhaps try updating the dependency to that?

Comment: yup, tried that too, no luck  though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

finally got it working by doing a manual npm install 'azure-storage'  to my mobile service.

I never thought of trying a manual npm install because other node modules I have in my package.json (like tracer, lodash) work fine with no manual npm install. Also, as I remember reading, if I just include the npm module I want to use in my mobile service's package.json and push it, mobile service on the server installs it and restarts, and I don't need to install myself manually. And thats what has been happening when my code was working till last week.

Comment: do you have a link available on how to do this?  I haven't found a console.

Comment: I am curious, where did you use the var azure = require('azure-storage');?

Comment: @GuyBen-Moshe, that is used in the custom API created in Azure Mobile serives with Node backend

Comment: @user1020853, sorry saw your question just today, sorry missed it and now its too late. anywayz, here is the link that explains how to create custom api in Azure - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-how-to-use-server-scripts/#custom-api